# WordPress: List posts with no comments

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have simple page that I want to display a list of posts that haven't been commented on yet. How would I do this? I presume it's some parameters I can add to the query_posts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately query_posts does not allow you to limit the query to `comment_count=0`. You can do this:

```
query_posts( 'orderby=comment_count&order=ASC' );
```

But that does not *only* display posts with zero comments, it just displays those with zero comments *first*.

The more involved (but better) solution is to use a custom query that specifically limits the query to posts with 0 comments, but that means you would have to create your own loop structure (at least [so far as I can tell](http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query))

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts
  WHERE
  {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish'
  AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.comment_count = 0
  ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date
  DESC;
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($query, OBJECT);

 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
 <?php global $post; ?>
 <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
 <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

 <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <!-- by <?php the_author() ?> --></small>
    <div class="entry">
       <?php the_content('Read the rest of this entry »'); ?>
    </div>
    <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> | <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>  
    <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></p>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
 <?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Does that seem within your knowledge to implement?

Comment: I've some experience with SQL and raw PHP so I think I could get my head around it. I'll just play around and see if I can get it working. Thanks for the awesome answer.

Answer (score 15):

You can set up a filter and query varaible to modify the SQL that queries the posts.  Add this to your theme's `functions.php` file

```
function filter_comment_count( $sql ){
    global $wpdb;
    $comment_count = get_query_var( 'comment_count' );

    if( is_numeric($comment_count) )
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.comment_count = %d ", $comment_count );

    return $sql;
}
```

Then you can call `query_posts( 'comment_count=0' );` (any number), you'll just want to add the filter beforehand,

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_comment_count'  );
```

And after you make the call, you may want to remove the filter as well.

```
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_comment_count' );
```

Comment: Yeah, what can ya do?  Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome. This helped solve finding posts with comments enabled by using $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.comment_status = 'open' "); instead.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as :

```
query_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'yourposttype', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'comment_count' => 0, ) );
```