# Only return posts with comments in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I'm surprised I cannot find much on this topic, perhaps I'm confused.

I am creating an archive page of comments. I want to get all posts with comments where I will list the post title followed by the all the comments for that post underneath using wp_list_comments or WP Comment Query.

My question is how can I filter WP_Query() so I can only return posts that have comments.

I've tried to modify this approach [list posts with no comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829733/wordpress-list-posts-with-no-comments) - postpostmodern's answer but I want to do the exact opposite.

Here is the function:

```
function filter_comment_count( $sql ){
    global $wpdb;
    $comment_count = get_query_var( 'comment_count' );

    if( is_numeric($comment_count) )
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.comment_count != %d ", $comment_count);

    return $sql;
    }
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_comment_count'  );
```

And then I'm attempting to use it in my loop, here is an excerpt:

```
$args = array (
    'comment_count'  => '0'
    'pagination'     => true,
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 
    while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();  
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

I guess the bit that is tripping me up is `AND {$wpdb->posts}.comment_count != %d` I want it to return `comment_count` not equal to 0 or whatever allows me to get only posts with comments in my `WP_Query($args);`

Also I'm not sure where to put `remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_comment_count' );`?

I realise there is `'orderby' => 'comment_count'` but that doesn't exactly help my situation as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not give the exact results you want, nor be efficient, but this is all I can think of:

Inside your loop, add:

```
$comments = get_comments(array('post_id' => $post->ID));
if ($comments !== '' && !empty($comments)) {
// The rest.
}
```

And that should output only the posts that have comments associated with them.

Edit:

There's also

```
    if( 0 < $post->comment_count ){

        // Output

    }
```

Which I retrieved from here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/125577/only-display-posts-with-comments

Answer (score 1):

Old question but if anyone stumbles on this as I did, WordPress 4.9 added 'comment_count' parameter to WP_Query.

The value can either be an integer of the number of comments you require or an array where the first argument is the 'value' and the second is a 'compare' search operator.

To only return posts with comments :

```
$args = array(
    'comment_count'  => array(
        'value'   => 0,
        'compare' => '>',
    ),
    'pagination'     => true,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
$the_query = WP_Query( $args );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#comment-parameters.